# Replicating data from localhost to online

Tags: php, mysql, replication

Greetings All

I need to replicate selected fields from tables from my localhost to my online database. Anyway scripts / method to do that easily? My boss says NO NO NO to mysql's built in replication feature.

Also I have started with a script that uses flags in the database to keep track of modified and already replicated data. As I have a couple of tables the script is getting long.

Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, coming to think about it, you can also enable binary logging, write a script to tail your mysql binlog for updates/inserts to your table/columns. Then the script mangles extracts the relevant info from your insert/update and pushes it upstream.

Comment: @Lmwangi : how to enable binary logging? How to write the script? How to push upstream? Any tutorials?

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html, have  a look at the mysqlbinlog manpage http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqlbinlog .

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [maatkit-table-sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html). It says table sync but i believe adding in support for specific columns might not be hard. If you do add column support, please contribute a patch upstream.